# Update package System.Data.SqlClient from 4.6.1 to 4.8.0 fills up connection pool

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

We run a Core ASP.net API controller under netcoreapp2.2 and everything works fine. After the last update of NuGet packages we encountered a bunch of connection timeouts of our backend. A deeper look into the logs showed that the following error message appeared:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Also thanks to this [lovely article from Michael](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/07/sql-performance/find-database-connection-leaks) we checked all the sleeping connections on our server. Due to the fact, that this SQL server doesn't serve any more clients, we simply removed the database and program name from the where clause to see all dangling connection:

```
-- From : Michael J Swart (https://sqlperformance.com/2017/07/sql-performance/find-database-connection-leaks)

declare @database_name sysname = N'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME_HERE';
declare @program_name sysname = N'.Net SqlClient Data Provider';

select 
    datediff(SECOND, s.last_request_end_time, getdate()) as seconds_asleep,
    s.last_request_start_time as lastreq,
        s.session_id,
        db_name(s.database_id) as database_name,
        s.host_name,
        s.host_process_id,  
        t.text as last_sql,
        s.program_name
from sys.dm_exec_connections c
join sys.dm_exec_sessions s
        on c.session_id = s.session_id
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle) t
where s.is_user_process = 1
        and s.status = 'sleeping'
        --and db_name(s.database_id) = @database_name
        --and program_name = @program_name         
        and datediff(second, s.last_request_end_time, getdate()) > 60
order by s.last_request_end_time;
```

And we found more then 100 of sleeping connections that are more than 6000 seconds asleep, filling up the connection pool. After checking all the changes we made between the latest defective release and the one before, our guess was the NuGet package [System.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient). So we made an hotfix where we downgrade only this package and push out a new release. After this weekend the API controller is still up and running and checking the connection pool with the script above shows less then 10 connections overall with a sleep timeout less then 300 seconds.

So it seems that after 4.6.1 an error is within this library (I didn't check 4.7.0, so maybe it is already there) that leads to these pooling errors (at least if you are on Core 2.2 and using EF core 2.2.6).

Comment: We've recently upgraded to System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.2 and starting to get strange exceptions from time to time: System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The requested operation cannot be completed because the connection has been broken.
Rolling back to 4.8.1 seems to help but still we're starting to get strange errors from Cassandra driver "Exception while trying borrow a connection from a pool". I wish I could have a look into diff for  System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.* but I couldn't find any.

Comment: I've opened an issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42132